# How to group list items into sequential tuples in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.6, sequence

I have a list which contains numbers in ascending order like

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
```

or

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I need to get a list of lists which contains the elements as a range items like

`[[start, end], [start, end]]` from the input list.

```
[[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 6]]
```

or

```
[[2, 5]]
```

where the elements that are not present in the input list should.

Here is the code I tried. But not sure how to get it.

```
zers = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
ls = []
for i, j in enumerate(zers):
    if i!=len(zers)-1 and zers[i+1]==zers[i]+1:last=i;continue
    else:
        if i==0:ls.append([i,i])
        else:ls.append([last, i])
print(ls)
```

It is supposed to give `[[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 6]]`
 But giving `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4]]`

Please feel free to make any modifications to my code or provide completely different solution.

I'm thinking that there should be a function from an existing library but just not sure. Please let me know if you comes across such.

Comment: The `enumerate` is adding confusion.  The pairs it produces are "index", "value".  You're only using the index, and ignoring the values, so it's equivalent to `for i in range(len(zers)):`.

Comment: Can I generate a list from `[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]` like `[[0, 3], [4, 6]]`? How do you make a difference?

Comment: [0, 3] is wrong because it doesn't contain 2.

Comment: @Shahroozevsky Your example is incorrect.  Read the post again.  For your example, the correct result would be `[[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 6]]`.  Your proposed output implies that `2` is present between `1` and `3`, which it clearly is not.

Comment: @Shahroozevsky No. The tuple items should be similar to range. `[Start, End]` All the numbers in that range should be present in the input list.

Comment: One problem with the posted code is that `last` isn't always defined when it's used.  Consider `[1, 3, 5]`.  In this case, `last` will never be defined, but it will try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `more_itertools.consecutive_groups` to make group of successive elements and then fetch 1st and last element from the groups:

```
import more_itertools as mit

iterable = [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
x = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(iterable)]

output = [[i[0],i[-1]] for i in x]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 6]]
```